# Highcharts error missing ModuleFor=arearange

Tags: reactjs

Error: Highcharts error #17: [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=arearange](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=arearange)

- missingModuleFor: arearange
  at f.p (highcharts.src.js:511)
  at e (highcharts.src.js:2124)

Answer (score 5):

Already solved, these imports are also needed in addition to the modules requiring them:

```js
import highchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
highchartsMore(Highcharts);
```